# Seeing how many posts have been made from male users (Using data from two tables to calculate number)

Tags: php, mysql

I have **two** tables:

`users` - Where gender information is stored:

```
id
username
gender
```

`user_thoughts`- Where all posts are stored:

```
id 
added_by
```

What I am trying to do is determine how many posts have been made by male and female users separately. But I am just completely stumped on how to achieve this. So far, I have the following:

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");

    // updating table posts_by_gender whenever admin logs in.

    // 1.Get gender of user to compare against the author or the thought
    $get_all_users_gen = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT gender FROM users WHERE account_type = 'user'");
        while ($getting_gen = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_all_users_gen)){
            $gender = $getting_gen['gender'];

    // 2. Get all posts
    $getting_thoughts = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT username FROM user_thoughts");
        $getting_th = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($getting_thoughts);
            $added_by = $getting_th['added_by'];

} // while closed
?>
```

I am just completely confused on what to write after this.

Summary:

1. Trying to check each row in `user_thoughts` table, get the `added_by` data (which is the same as `username` from `users` table) and see if that user is male or female.

   2. At the end of the check, I need a variable which holds a number of how many posts belong to male users, and how many to female.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a Join... An example given below

```
SELECT * FROM `user_thoughts` LEFT JOIN users ON user_thoughts.added_by = users.username WHERE users.gender= "male"
```

This will get all user thoughts by male... Then you can do a `mysqli_num_rows($query)` to get the count.

You can do the same for females...

However, if you only need the count, it may be adviseable to run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM `user_thoughts` LEFT JOIN users ON user_thoughts.added_by = users.username WHERE users.gender= "male"
```

and this would return the number of rows directly.